# How do I slice X rows from a Dataframe begining at a specific label index in Pandas and Python

Tags: python, pandas

I want to specify a label index, then slice int X rows from a dataframe. And I do not necessarily know my end label. My labels are usually timestamps, but that should not matter. I am having trouble achieving this, mixing labels and integer numbers of rows wanted.

so if:

```
df= pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(8,3), columns = list('abc'), index = list('lmnopqrs'))
```

How do I get the result given by this code:

```
df.loc['q':'o':-1]
```

BUT, if I only know the 'q' index? So I want to something that returns logic like this:

```
df.loc['q':"3 rows only":-1]
```

So normally I would never know which int index the 'q' is, but I would know its name, and I do not know where in the dataframe it is. Thanks.

Comment: The example you show is slicing backward.  Is that what you want to do?

Comment: Yes, backwards in this case. But technique should work either way.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there are better ways to do this, But You can use `df.index` to access the indexes in the DataFrame, and also `df.index.tolist()` to access the index as list.

So in your case, `df.index.tolist()` would give -

```
In [13]: df.index.tolist()
Out[13]: ['l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's']
```

Then, you can find the index of `q` in that list, using `list.index()` method and then get the element that is `2` indexes before `q` . Example -

```
In [19]: df.index[df.index.tolist().index('q')-2]
Out[19]: 'o'
```

You can use this to index your DataFrame , Example -

```
In [20]: df.loc['q':df.index[df.index.tolist().index('q')-2]:-1]
Out[20]:
          a         b         c
q  0.791467  0.703116  0.268405
p  0.643924  0.434607  0.918549
o  0.630881  0.209446  0.351309
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the `.ix` attribute:

```
index = df.index.searchsorted('q')  # or just a number if you already have it.
offset = 3
df.ix[index : index - offset : -1]
```

Comment: this will return indices `s , r , q` not `o , p , q`

Comment: Thanks @NaderHisham - I've changed it to go the right way - I was confused by the reverse indexing there.